# jquery, how to resolve this multiple chain failure

Tags: jquery

I don't how to resolve this situation. I have this first dropdown menu with ID = PK1. I will force it to some value which goes off with cgi.perl and alters the second drop down menu with ID=#PK1_DEVICE_NAME_SELECTION based on some mysql lookup.

My coding below to force the val('$TEMP{DEVICE1_NAME}') doesn't work!

If I put an alert between the middle these 4 lines, it works. How do I resolve this?

```
                // FORCING VALUES FOR THE DROP DOWN MENU 1
                \$("#PK1").val('$TEMP{PDK1}');
                \$("#PK1").trigger('change');

                \$("#PK1_DEVICE_NAME_SELECTION").val('$TEMP{DEVICE1_NAME}');
                \$("#PK1_DEVICE_NAME_SELECTION").trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in your ajax callback. Something like this:

```
$("#PK1").val('$TEMP{PDK1}');
$("#PK1").trigger('change');

$('#PK1').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'whatever.cgi',
        success:function(data){
            $("#PK1_DEVICE_NAME_SELECTION").val('$TEMP{DEVICE1_NAME}');
            $("#PK1_DEVICE_NAME_SELECTION").trigger('change'); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: but i already have this change function somewhere else, seems i have to define it twice??

Comment: No, you just need to fire the ajax call inside the change observer